# Combine child component data into one object inside Parent Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, material-ui, react-hooks

I am trying to create objects from data sent from same child component inside its parent component.

On submit button in parent get all the child components data and append it into an object and pass it to Parent.

Parent Component

```
const [values, setValues] = useState();

const appendFeesData = (fee) => {
    const key = Object.keys(fee)[0];
    const value = Object.values(fee)[0];
    setValues({...values, [key]: value})
    console.log("Values", values);
}
```

Inside JSX

```
{
  feesObjData.map((feeObj) => {
    return (
        <CheckboxInputFee
            ref={checkboxInputRef}
            getInputValue={appendFeesData}
            name={feeObj.name}
            inputValue={feeObj.inputValue}
            label={feeObj.label}
            InputAdornment={feeObj.inputAdornment}
        />
    );
  })
 }
```

Child Component

```
const [checkboxValue, setCheckboxValue] = useState(false);
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(props.inputValue);

const handleCheckbox = ({ target }) => {
    setCheckboxValue(target.checked);
}

const handleInputValue = ({ target }) => {
    setInputValue(target.value);
}

const createObj = () => {
    const fieldName = props.name;
    const value = parseInt(inputValue);
    return ({
        [fieldName]: value
    })
}

useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    sendInputValue(){
        const valueObj = createObj();
        console.log(valueObj);
        props.getInputValue(valueObj);
    }
}));
```

Inside JSX

```
<Grid item xs={6}>
  <FormControlLabel
    control={<Checkbox
      name={props.name}
      checked={checkboxValue}
      onChange={handleCheckbox}
      color="primary" 
    />}
    label={props.label}
  />
</Grid>

<Grid item xs={6}>
  <TextField
    required
    id={props.name}
    name={props.name}
    fullWidth
    disabled={!checkboxValue}
    onChange={handleInputValue}
    value={inputValue}
    variant="outlined"
    margin="dense"
    InputProps={{
      startAdornment: (
        <InputAdornment position="start">{props.InputAdornment}</InputAdornment>
      )
    }}
  />
</Grid>
```

The appendFeesData method gets one parameter from every child component as `fee = {name: value}`. This method should create an object containing all the child component values like....

```
{
 name1: value1,
 name2: value2,
 etc
}
```

Comment: You have only defined your use case. Please specify what question or issue you face solving this.

Comment: You can pass a method from your parent component to its child component. On select the child component calls the method and the method should update the  appendFeesData.

Comment: @AmanGupta I am not able to get all the child element data instead only getting the last input data to parent.